# how to view code in github repository on browser

Tags: github, view, repository

github Newbie question
[I've seen other posts related to github here, but if I'm not in the right place then I'll be grateful if someone could direct me.]

This is driving me nuts! I created a repository on github.com and all I want is to view the code in my browser. FYI, I looked at
[How to view repository on GitHub](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14151595/how-to-view-repository-on-github)

which was not relevant.

When I go to github (https://github.com/geraldrharp/backup) I have a private repository called backup. When I log in and "view code" in the repository, I see the webpage copied as a screen shotbelow. Obviously, I don't see the code. And I've searched high and low, and can't figure out how to see my code.
I've searched the internet many times, but no one else seems to have my problem. Which is weird. Also, searched stackXXX sites.

I do have github desktop, but I get no further there. And I'm positive there is a way to see my code in a browser, which is what I really want. 'Cause I need to view the code from another computer on which I don't have the authority to install programs.

Please help!

[image: screenshot of webpage in browser window]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure (and how are you sure) that there is something pushed in this repository? This window usually appears right after a repository is created without anything in it.

Comment: I'm pretty sure? I thought I had cloned this repo to another computer several months ago.  But that is a good point. I'll try to verify there is code there. Thx

Comment: @GerryHarp If this answer helped you resolve this issue, feel free marking it as an accepted answer :)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/4359451/elona-tamakauskait%c4%97
You were right! I found another repository I'd made long ago, and I could see that just fine. Man, that was so frustrating! Thanks